# How to trigger mouse right click when pressing any other key?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, jquery-events

I tried this. But this doesn't work. Any other way?

```
if (e.keyCode === 93) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#element').trigger({
                    type: 'mousedown',
                    which: 3
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'mousedown', use 'mouseup'. It's works.

```
if (e.keyCode === 93) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element').trigger({
                type: 'mouseup',
                which: 3
            });
        }
```